# Sencha touch - Why don't my buttons work?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

[SOLVED]

I am following this tutorial [link](http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-touch-2-tabs-toolbars)

I have a buttons in my Main view like so

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    config: {
        items:[
            {
                text:'hello',
                xtype:'button',
                action:'pingHomeBadge',
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

And my main controller looks like

```
    Ext.define('Sencha.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            starButton:'button[action=pingHomeBadge]',
        },
        control: {
            starButton: {
                tap:'incrementHomeBadge',
            },
        }
    },

    incrementHomeBadge: function() {
        alert("hello");
    },
});
```

The button gets displayed but when I click on the button nothing happens. Anybody know what I am doing wrong? I pretty much copy pasted the code from the tutorial. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try this way:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
       // starButton:'button[action=pingHomeBadge]',
    },
    control: {
        'button[action=pingHomeBadge]': {
            tap:'incrementHomeBadge',
        },
    }
},

incrementHomeBadge: function() {
    alert("hello");
},
```

});

Also check whether this controller is getting loaded or not. As in mentioned in the app.js

Comment: Yea that was the problem, I didn't declare the controller in app.js

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

Actually they are not in your control, but your refs look fine... i dont see anything with your code so i suspect the issue lies elsewhere... why not just compare your source with the source code of the tutorial? http://github.com/senchalearn/Tabs-and-Toolbars

Comment: I have already done that in my controller. I have given the code for my controller in the question.